# set of changes at db using cassandra reactive repository

Tags: cassandra, spring-data, project-reactor, spring-data-cassandra

I'm trying to do some mixed logic at 2 cassandra tables with projectreactor and ReactiveCassandraRepository.
tables are looks like this:

1) userId (pk) | hashId

2) hashIf (pk) | userId

when i getting new userId, i need to change that value at both tables, using spring data.
I trying that:

```
fun change(userId: String, oldUserId: String) {
    userIdToHashRepository
        .findAllByUserId(oldUserId)
        .flatMap { response ->
            // response is object like Check(val userId: String, val hash: String)
            userIdToHashRepository.saveUserIdAndHash(
                userId,
                response.hash
            )
            hashToUserIdRepository.updateUserIdByHash(
                userId,
                response.hash
            )
        }
        .doOnNext {
            userIdToHashRepository.deleteAllByUserId(oldUserId.toString())
        }
        .subscribe()
}
```

when i start with that values at tables:

```
1) userId | hashId
    111     111111

2) hashId | userId
   111111  111
```

and `newUserId=444`

I getting that:

```
1) 

    userId | hashId

        111     111111
```

( no line is appends and old line is not dropped, this is sad)

```
2) hashId | userId

   111111  444

   111111  111
```

(line is appends, but i want to drop old line)

So
please, can you say, why only second method after flatMap is working? 
why doOnNext is not work?

and how to fix that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, y don't know why, but if i put each "db-call" to 'then {}' expression, it is worked

Answer (score 0):

What if you do someting like this? You should always chain calls.

```
fun change(userId: String, oldUserId: String) {
    userIdToHashRepository
        .findAllByUserId(oldUserId)
        .flatMap ( response ->
            // response is object like Check(val userId: String, val hash: String)
             userIdToHashRepository.saveUserIdAndHash(
                userId,
                response.hash
            )}
         .flatMap( response -> hashToUserIdRepository.updateUserIdByHash(
                userId,
                response.hash
            )
        .doOnNext {
            userIdToHashRepository.deleteAllByUserId(oldUserId.toString())
        }
        .subscribe()
}
```